# SSMS 18.4 Error opening database properties dialog box Azure SQL DB Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance, ssms

I have three databases in an Azure SQL DB Managed Instance. I am using SSMS 18.4. One database I can right-click, choose **Properties**, and the dialog box comes up normally. The other two databases give me the following error.

[image]

I have spent a couple of hours Googling with no results. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure support pointed me to [this article](https://aka.ms/j9ROp7wl) which worked to cure the problem. Apparently the issue was multiple old entries in the msdb backup sets. All left over from when I was experimenting with Azure SQL MI Migration Assistant. Interestingly, the database where the Properties dialog always worked also has multiple old entries in the backup sets. So it's still a head scratcher!

Revising this answer because the link above is dead, and I gave a more complete answer in [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/319904/108519) on dba.stackexchange.